# -bash: django-admin.py: command not found (Django Installation)

Tags: python, django, django-admin, project, installation

Sorry I realize this is a very novice question: I am not yet skilled in Python. I have tried to follow a few basic django tutorials to get a simple site running. I am getting the error `-bash: django-admin.py: command not found` in Mac Terminal when trying to use the command `django-admin.py startproject FirstBlog` function.

If I try `python django-admin.py startproject FirstBlog` instead, terminal returns

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
 from django.core import management
 ImportError: No module named django.core
```

I have tried these commands from different directories, but still the same result. This is MacOSX 10.5.8 and Bitnami DjangoStack 1.4. I have tried to find the answer elsewhere on stackoverflow and google: people have suggested changing the path to django-admin.py. I have tried but either have written my paths incorrectly or this isn't the problem.

If more information is required I will gladly supply it. Thank you.

### EDIT

I have abandoned the BitNami DjangoStack after a lot of difficulty installing the program. I have reverted to installing Django/mysql manually, which turns out to be a lot easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Bitnami supplies its own version of Python and that's where Django is installed so you need to make sure you are running that Python and not an Apple-supplied system Python, for example.  According to the [quick start guide](http://bitnami.org/files/stacks/djangostack/1.4-0/djangostack.pdf), it looks you can either use their supplied console application which should ensure you are running with their Python:

```
/Applications/djangostack-1.4-0/use_djangostack
```

or you may be able to use the absolute path to that Python:

```
/Applications/djangostack-1.4-0/python/bin/python django-admin.py
```

Comment: I get this message after entering `/Applications/djangostack-1.4-0/python/bin/python django-admin.py` in Terminal:  `admins-macbook:~ Admin$ /Applications/djangostack-1.4-0/python/bin/python
/Applications/djangostack-1.4-0/python/bin/python: line 3: /Applications/django/scripts/setenv.sh: No such file or directory`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you Ned, but after a lot of problems with this BitNami application I have just installed django/mysql manually. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry you found this problem (I'm from the BitNami team). I tried to reproduce the issue in case it was a bug in our installation however I couldn't reproduce the issue. Indications from Ned worked for me.